How to enable direct connection to Tailscale's exit node with Gluetun
This is a Docker setup that runs a Tailscale node, routes traffic through Gluetun with NordVPN connected, and advertises the Tailscale node as an exit node.
services:
  gluetun:
    image: qmcgaw/gluetun
    restart: unless-stopped
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun
    environment:
      - VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER=nordvpn
      - VPN_TYPE=openvpn
      - OPENVPN_USER=${NORDVPN_OPENVPN_USER}
      - OPENVPN_PASSWORD=${NORDVPN_OPENVPN_PASSWORD}
      - SERVER_COUNTRIES=${NORDVPN_SERVER_COUNTRIES}
    ports:
      - 41641:41641 # tailscale port
      - 3478:3478 # stun port
  tailscale:
    image: tailscale/tailscale:latest
    network_mode: "service:gluetun"
    restart: unless-stopped
    cap_add:
      - net_admin
      - sys_module
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/tailscale:/var/lib/tailscale
      - /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun
    environment:
      - TS_AUTHKEY=${TAILSCALE_AUTHKEY}
      - TS_EXTRA_ARGS=--advertise-exit-node
      - TS_STATE_DIR=/var/lib/tailscale
      - TS_USERSPACE=true
      - TS_HOSTNAME=${TAILSCALE_HOSTNAME}
    depends_on:
      gluetun:
        condition: service_healthy

The problem is that it seems only relayed connection's through DERP are happening. Is it possible to establish direct connection to the exit node, considering NordVPN doesn't allow port forwarding?
